# When is it appropriate to use Qt signals to communicate DOWN the dependency tree?

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots, qobject

I'm working with some code that I didn't write, and am confused about the practice of, essentially, using signals and slots for absolutely everything.

I understand using them to communicate UP the dependency tree (basically, used as callbacks). For example, if we have the following classes:

`MainWindow` -> `SomeDialog` -> `SomeView` -> `SomeModel`

... And `SomeModel` is capable of changing some shared application state, it may emit a signal `changed()` which is connected to a slot of `SomeView`, which in turn sends a signal to `SomeDialog`, etc.

This is valuable because it ensures there is no circular dependency between an object and its child; `SomeModel` doesn't have to know anything about `SomeView` or its parents in order to communicate with it.

But *why would you do the reverse*? That is, if I have `AnotherDialog`, `AnotherView` and `AnotherModel`, and `AnotherModel` needs to know when the state is changed in `SomeModel`, why would I use signals to communicate in the *downward* direction? The path of signal propagation ends up being:

`SomeModel` -> `SomeView` -> `SomeDialog` -> `MainWindow` -> `AnotherDialog` -> `AnotherView` -> `AnotherModel`

This is difficult to debug, confusing, and (as far as I can tell) completely unnecessary. Once the signal is propagated to `MainWindow`, it can just call a method on its instance of `AnotherDialog` directly, there's no need for signals... right?

I realize this question may be overly vague, but I wanted to make sure I'm not ignoring some Qt design principle before I go and refactor all the old code.

Comment: Is there a reason you would be emitting a new signal in each class instead of connecting a signal from SomeModel directly to AnotherModel?

Comment: @thuga Because MainWindow doesn't know about SomeModel or AnotherModel; it just constructs the dialog, which in turn constructs the view, etc. Which is a design flaw in itself, but I'm trying to solve one problem at a time here...

Comment: Well, one reason to have signals and slots, though it doesn't exactly concern this situation, is if you have let's say 100 objects. So instead of calling each ones function separately, you can just emit a signal that is connected to some slot of these objects. Other than that and thread affinity as mentioned by RA, I can't find any reason to use signals and slots instead of calling a function directly. Maybe if you don't want to use global variables but local variables instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reason for using signals *might* be because `AnotherDialog`, `AnotherView` and/or `AnotherModel` have different [thread affinities](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/thread-basics.html#qobject-and-threads) (but even then it might have been preferable to use `QMetaObject::invokeMethod()`).

If all of these classes exist within a single thread, then there wouldn't be any good reason to use signals.

There do appear to be other design flaws here, but looking at your comments it seems as though you're aware of them.

Comment: I considered the thread affinity angle, but these objects are all on the same thread and that's unlikely to change. So I guess I got my answer, thanks! I'll accept it after I give a bit of time for other people to weigh in (if they want).